# definition of critical point defined in terms of differential map

Tags: differential-geometry

I am having a problem understanding the definition of a critical point in 
do carmo's Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces. 
He notes in page 58 that a point $p \in U $ is a critical point of F if 
$ dF_{p} : R^{n} \to R^{m}$ is not a surjective mapping.

If we have a map F from $R^{2} \to R^{3}$,on any point the Jacobian matrix of F will have
rank of at most 2 and the columns of the Jacobian matrix would span a two dimensional plane. Doesn't this imply that the differential map is not surjective?

Comment: Yes. All points of the domain are critical points.

Comment: I believe it should not be injective instead of not surjective.